# Implement onBackPressed for 2 fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I've looked at multiple questions, haven't found solution yet.

I've youtube player SDK imported and a webview. One is in Live_fragment and another Article_Fragment.

This is the onBackPressed code that causes the crash:

```
@Override
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webViewE.canGoBack() || youTubePlayer.isFullScreen()) {
        youTubePlayer.exitFullScreen()
        webViewE.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Now, `webViewE.canGoBack` and `youTubePlayer.isFullScreen()` alone works fine (if I only put in one of them), but if they're both together in the function, I get:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference" and app crashes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: what behaviour do you expect when `webViewE` is null/canGoBack returns false and `youTubePlayer.isFullScreen` returns true? Is iy possible for the webViewE to successfully run `goBacK` if `canGoBack` returns false?

Answer (score 0):

This means your WebView variable is null at the time of the `onBackPressed` invocation. You need to make sure you properly initialise it and ensure it hasn't been nullified somehow up until possible calls to `onBackPressed`. If you want to axe this condition in the event that the WebView may be null, you can just add a check for null alongside your current check, i.e.:

```
@Override
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if ((webViewE != null && webViewE.canGoBack()) || youTubePlayer.isFullScreen()) {
        youTubePlayer.exitFullScreen()
        webViewE.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, until I go to Article_Fragment and back to Live_Fragment. Then isFullScreen is always false.